# get current username in laravel route file without passing from controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello i want to know that how can i access the current username in my laravel route file? i want to add current user name as prefix in my url but i don't want to pass username as parameter for every route call because project is already completed so its is a complex and time consuming task. so please suggest how can I get current username. 
Here is my code:

```
Route::prefix(/Auth::user()->name)->group(function () {
   Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@test')->name('test');
});

<a href="{{route('test')}}">
```

Thanks in advance.

Note:- I don't want to pass username from templates or controller because its complex and time consuming as project is already done.

Comment: What is your expected route ? can give a sample route?

Comment: Its should be like:
/adam/home

Comment: check my answer

Comment: All of your routes are named routes ?

Comment: not all but most of them are named route. i will add manually for url().

Answer (score 0):

> Routes are registered before Session is initialized. So you can't access the authenticated user in the routes file.

So you have to register new routes with a dummy username prefix as,

```
Route::prefix('{username}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Just add a param `{username}` & no need it use anywahere. Keep this route group at the end of the routes file.

Re-generate your routes as,

```
<a href="{{ url(auth()->user()->name . '/test') }}">
```

Comment: Auth::user()->name return error 'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object' and Auth::user() return null.

Comment: this is what I mention above there are a lot of url calls in my project so its a complex way to pass username as parameter with every url. thats why i want to generate url prefix in route file.

Comment: It's just a dummy param. You have to generate those routes anyway in the templates right ?

Comment: routes are already generated in template and there are like /home so now i want to append username at runtime like /adam/home on my route file.
i don't want to pass username from template and controller like this: 
<a href="{{ url(auth()->user()->name . '/test') }}">

Its should be like 
<a href="{{ url('/test') }}"> and append username in my route file.

Comment: to be more clear, if you have routes like '/home' in the templates, how a user is going to access 'adam/home' which is not generated anywhere in your templates? what do you expect if a user clicks on '/home' ? it should be redirected to 'adam/home' ?

Comment: Further more, to explain simply, if you register routes as `Route::prefix(/Auth::user()->name)`, they would be new routes. `/adam/home` & `/home` would be 2 separate routes. you must change the already generated routes with the prefix or you should redirect the old routes to the new ones with the user prefix. hope you understand.

Comment: i simply want that when user click on /home the in route file username should be append at run time like we use hard coded prefix.
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@test');
});

<a href="{{ route( 'test') }}">

if we do this 'admin' will be appended automatically without calling complete url.

Comment: That's what called 'redirecting'.

Comment: then how can i do it dynamically?

Comment: Can you update your question with what you actually have ? the template & the routes. Need to see how they are used

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass Auth user from routes/web.php , you need to pass paramter in your route .

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth','prefix'=>'/'],function () {
   Route::get({username}, 'HomeController@test');
});
```

in your controller :

```
 public function test(Request $request,$username){
      $user=User::where('name',$username)->first();
      if($user){
        return response()->json((array('status'=>'success','user'=>$user));
      }else{
        return response()->json(array('status'=>'error','message'=>'user not found'));
      }
   }
```

Comment: Not working same issue auth()->() is null. Auth::check() also gives null for logged in user in route file. but showing user in controller.

Comment: this is because you have to pass parameter to controller

Comment: i don't want to pass a parameter from template or controller because i have to pass parameter for every route calls and project is completed so its a complex task to do.